# Tax related problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to end up with \$400,000 after tax

Any amount above \$220,000 is taxed at 53.53%.
What is the amount above \$220,000 minus the 53.53% that will give me \$400,000 after tax

Comment: Is there any tax on income under $220K?

Answer (score 0):

We need some amount $x$ such that

$$400,000 = (1-0.5353)x$$

After setting this up, we can just divide both sides by $0.4647$. I get that $x$ is about $860,770.39$.